# How to do some manual Git Update of a forked project?

Tags: git, github

(New to Git and Github)

Hi,

For a project that i'm developing i am depending on a project that needs to be adapted. While the source of the project are available for download, it sounds like it is not available on SVCS repository such as Git or SVN.

Hence, I was wondering how in that context shall i aim at updating my fork. Can i just download the new source every time (in a separate folder*) and try to update my local Git repository of that project, from that folder* ?

What should be the right workflow for that ?

Many thanks,

M

Answer (score 1):

You will be managing your own dependencies.

If the source of your dependency is unavailable, I recommend doing it this way:

- Create blank repository and put their code there.
- All updates in this project will be put in this repository.
- If I have a dependency management tool that can use VCS, I'd depend on this repository.
- If not, I'll add this repository as submodule.

You can track the changes in that dependency project separately. This is useful if you use that dependency on multiple projects.

Comment: 1- All updates in this project will be put in this repository. You mean simply replacing the content of the folder each time ?

Comment: Could please clarify this 2 points a little bit more. It sounds clear what you said, although i'm still learning Git right now: A - If I have a dependency management tool that can use VCS, I'd depend on this repository.
B- If not, I'll add this repository as submodule.

Comment: 1. Yes, you would replace the content of the folder. Or delete everything and add the new ones so you can see if there are deleted files.

Comment: 2. Let me explain. I'm a PHP developer and in PHP, there's this tool called [composer](http://getcomposer.org) and you create a file called `composer.json` file, then you specify which third party projects you want to install. I don't know if a similar program exists in another language.

If you don't know any, then use git [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) or git [subtree](http://makingsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-git-subtrees-for-repository-separation/). Technically, these tools will let you add an external repository to yours. Google it for more info.